# How to pass params from URL to ajax request? Express web app

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, parameters, get

I want to pull the params from a URL (after navigating to that URL) to use in an AJAX get request. The AJAX request will use the params in a client side function to get data specific to a user-profile.

URL example: www.website.com/user-profile/12345

Ajax request:

```
var theParams = // here I don't know how to access the params 12345 from above URL
var getDataWithParams = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getData/:' + theParams,
        success: function (data) {
            // process data 
        }


    });
};

getDataWithParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
// var url = window.location.href; if u wish to use url of page you had navigated to.

var url = 'www.website.com/user-profile/12345';

var userId = url.split('/').pop(); // pop gets last element
```